# How to change Content-Type:application/json into html in response header

Tags: json, apache, symfony, symfony-2.3, fosrestbundle

I am setting up symfony 3 apache 2.4 and mysql environment for API development... I have just started and the index.html.twig page appears like this:[image]

and my response header looks json format instead of html
[image]

my config.yml has FOSRest Configuration as:

```
# FOSRest Configuration
fos_rest:
    body_listener: true
    format_listener:
        rules:
            - { path: '^/', priorities: ['json'], fallback_format: json, prefer_extension: false }
    param_fetcher_listener: true
    view:
        view_response_listener: 'force'
        formats:
            json: true

# Nelmio CORS Configuration
nelmio_cors:
    defaults:
        allow_credentials: false
        allow_origin: ['*']
        allow_headers: ['*']
        allow_methods: ['GET', 'POST', 'PUT', 'DELETE', 'OPTIONS']
        max_age: 3600
        hosts: []
        origin_regex: false
```

my question: how can I make my page rendered as html ?

Comment: Just for grins try changing path: '^/' to path: '^/api'

Answer (score 0):

In your FOSRest configuration, you tell him to handle the response when the URL match `^/` which is every URLs.

If you want to use FOSRest formatting for everything but the main page, you can configure it as follow :

```
fos_rest:
    # ...
    format_listener:
            rules:
                - { path: '^/.+', priorities: ['json'], fallback_format: json, prefer_extension: false }
                - { path: '^/', stop: true }
```